# How do I update a WPF control based on console output from a Process?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process

I have a simple console application that reports progress to standard output. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

which produces this output:

```
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

I would like to call this application via a .NET `Process`, and update a WPF control (ProgressBar, specifically) asynchronously:

```
private void Run()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            ProgressBar.Value = double.Parse(e.Data);
        }
    });
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
}
```

When I run this it writes to the console without issue, but understandably complains about trying to access ProgressBar from a different thread, so I wrap it with an invoke:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    ProgressBar.Value = double.Parse(e.Data);
});
```

However, it freezes when it hits the invoke. Presumably there's a deadlock occurring, though I don't understand why.

Looking around, it seems like [`Process.SynchronizingObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject.aspx) was designed to fix these situations, but I can't see how to use it from WPF, as the controls don't have an `ISynchronizeInvoke` property.

Comment: If you declare something like `public System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatch = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;` when the application is initialized and use that dispatcher, does it change the behaviour?

Comment: @pay: No change, whether I put `dispatch` in `MainWindow` or `App`.

Comment: Hm, so even if the dispatcher was created on the UI thread, it still deadlocks? Maybe remove from the inside of that event handler as well.

Comment: @pay: Remove what from the inside of the event handler?

Comment: The call to `Invoke`

Comment: @pay: If I remove the invoke I get the error that I'm accessing the progress bar on a different thread than it was created on.

Comment: No I mean take the entire call out of the event handler, the `Invoke` is inside `+= new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>`

Comment: @pay: Still not following you.

Comment: Create a new line above where it says `Process.Start();` and put `dispatch.Invoke(() =>
{
    ProgressBar.Value = double.Parse(e.Data);
});` there.

Comment: @pay: `e.Data` only exists within the event handler.

Comment: Yes, create a holder for it above the event handler. `double holder = 0;`, then inside the event handler, put `e.data` into `holder`, then pass `holder` to the `Invoke`

Comment: @pay: Yes, works fine there because it's updating the progress bar from the same thread. The invoke isn't even necessary in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> WaitForExit() makes the current thread wait until the associated process terminates. It should be called after all other methods are called on the process. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the Exited event.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, you should not use `process.WaitForExit()` due to the fact that it will make the UI thread to wait for the process to exit. If you want to execute code only after the process exits, handle `process.Exited` event.

Also, `process.ErrorDataReceived`, `process.OutputDataReceived` and `process.Exited` are raised in another thread. In order for them to interact with your controls in the UI thread (namely, your `ProgressBar`), you should handle the events in this manner:

```
private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do additional processing with e.Data if this is what you desire
        ProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> { ProgressBar.Value=double.Parse(e.Data); }));
    }
```

Using `ProgressBar.Dispatcher` ensures that the dispatcher of the thread in which your ProgressBar exists is called.
Note that I did not run this code, it is adapted from what I use.

Please forgive any mistakes, first post.
Also, I'm sorry for reviving such an old post, but this came as a result from Google, and I hope I can help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Would recommend binding your `ProgressBar` to an object that fires [change notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and updating the property on that object. That way you can avoid directly using the `Dispatcher` and accessing the view (which you probably shouldn't anyway).

```
private double _Progress = 0;
public double Progress
{
    get { return _Progress; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Progress)
        {
            _Progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Dummy updates, 10% every second
new Thread(p =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Progress += 10;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}).Start();
```

```xml
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Height="20px" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Can you show code of how that would work in this case?

Comment: This is utterly trivial, i am sure you can do this.

Comment: @CraigW: Seriously?

Comment: It's a nice textbook example of databinding, but not relevant in my scenario (console output from a `Process`).

Comment: You already have the code to read the output, the only thing that changes in your code is that you assign a property instead of the `ProgressBar.Value` directly...